# Azure Deployment Angular .NetCore

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a project .NetCore Angular and i try to publish it on azure using FTP.

Once the FTP is done publishing the files, and i access the website i am getting an error

npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20

npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37

Please take note on my local environment i am using **node version 12.14.0**

I am suspecting the error happens of my node version on my Azure Enviroment. My Question right now,is that how do i update

node version on my azure environment.

Thanks In advance.

Sincerely yours,

Pong

Answer (score 0):

- You can set the **WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION** in the portal by checking the nodejs version from D://program files(x86)/nodejs.-

  - From all the available versions, choose one and update **WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION**. Also keep in mind that Azure Functions runtime v1(~1) locks your node version at v6.11.
  - To use a configurable Node.js runtime, you'll, need to upgrade your Functions runtime to v2.x:

[image: Edit the version]

Go through this doc for more reference : [NodeJS Version reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version)